# Multiple WebAPI Projects acting as if it was a single api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm not entirely sure what we are trying to do is that out of the ordinary but I cant figure out how to actually do this.

What we want to do is have multiple independently deployable WebApi projects all running on the same port. Effectively we want a something like this below:

```
http://api.company.com/api/Sales/v1/[Customer]
http://api.company.com/api/Sales/v3/[Products]
http://api.company.com/api/Sales/v5/[Orders]
http://api.company.com/api/Sales/v2/[Pricing]
http://api.company.com/api/Sales/v1/[Rewards]
```

With People, Products, Orders, Pricing, and Rewards to be its own independent WebAPI project.

However we also want to be able to define the route after http://api.company.com/api/Sales within each of the projects so each of them can define their own versioning can it can be controlled by different teams.

Right now I am working on setting up our first new WebApi project and inside my controller I have it doing the following.

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/Customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{argCustomerNumber}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
    public HttpResponseMessage LoadCustomer(string argCustomerNumber)
    {
        //Loades customer into a HttpResponseMessage
    }


    [Route("{argCustomerNumber}")]
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage ReplaceCustomerData(string argCustomerNumber, [FromBody] CustomerData argCustomerData)
    {
        //Updates customer in Database
    }


    [Route("{argCustomerNumber}/LicenseAgreements")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage LoadLicenseAgreement(string argCustomerNumber)
    {
        //Loads if they have signed the agreement
    }


    //.... You get the idea
}
```

When we are deploying this to our IIS server we have it setup under a virtual folder structure.

[image: Folder structure. Company(Website)->VirtDirectory->VirtDirectory->WebApprication]

With it setup this way it only responds when I call http://api.company.com/api/Sales/v1/Customer/v1/Customer/1 when I am expecting it to respond to http://api.company.com/api/Sales/v1/Customer/1

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: You should assign a new port number to each service.

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with IIS url rewrite.

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that each api is "rooted" at api/sales/Customer (or Products, etc)...  You could change the route prefix to exclude the Customer part

Comment: @SonicTheLichen It's not rooted at Customer. It's rooted at sales.

Comment: @neo from a web api project context, it's rooted at the virtual directory.  It won't respond to requests above that ... For instance, your api won't even respond until a request hits "...Sales/Customer"... then, you are adding a routeprefix on top of that